# Django: How to create a queryset from a model relationship?

Tags: django, django-models

I have been struggling with grasping relations for some time and would be very grateful if someone can help me out on this issue.

I have a relation that connects the User model to a ProcessInfo model via one to many and then I have a relation that connects the ProcessInfo to the ProcessAssumptions as One to one

Is there a way to use the User id to get all ProcessAssumptions related to all processes from that user.

I would like to retrieve a queryset of all ProcessAssumptions related to a user id

Here is the model relation :

```
class ProcessInfo(models.Model):

    process_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)

    user_rel = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class ProcessAssumptions(models.Model):
    
    completion_time = models.FloatField(default='0')

    process_rel_process = models.OneToOneField(ProcessInfo, primary_key = True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using field referencing for foreign keys.

```py
process_assumption_objects = ProcessAssumptions.objects.filter(process_rel_process__user_rel=<user_id>)
```

Replace `<user_id>` with the id you wish to query for.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a relationship to model X in another model Y, all related Ys can be accessed from an instance of X by `X_instance.Y_set.all()`. You can even perform the regular `filter` or `get` operations on that. `X_instance.Y_set` is the default object manager for Y (same as Y.objects), but it's filtered to only contain the objects that are related to X_instance.
So in this specific case, you can get all `ProcessInfo` objects for a certain user like this:

```py
user = User.objects.get(the_user_id)

required_assumptions = [proc_info.process_assumptions for proc_info in user.process_info_set.all()]
```

This might be a bit hard to read with `_set` suffix, so you can define a `related_name` argument while defining the relation on the model.
like:

```py
# in class ProcessInfo
user_rel = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='processes')

# and now you can do
some_user.processes.all()
```